# Как получить элементы ListView, которые не входят в текущую область обзора?

Tags: c#, winapi

UI AutomationElementsTree:

> Елементы вне текущей области видимости:

[image]

> Элементы, видимые в данный момент:

[image]

Проблема в том, что я не могу взаимодействовать (выделить например) с объектами вне зоны видимости

************** Текст исключения **************
System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotEnabledException: The operation is not allowed on a nonenabled element.
   в MS.Internal.Automation.ElementUtil.Invoke(AutomationPeer peer, DispatcherOperationCallback work, Object arg)
   в MS.Internal.Automation.SelectionItemProviderWrapper.Select()
   в MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.CheckError(Int32 hr)
   в System.Windows.Automation.SelectionItemPattern.Select()
   в AutomationElementsTree.mainWindow.selectionMenu(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: не хочешь ли ты раскрыть и выбрать ? почему нельзя раскрыть?

Comment: Не понял. Раскрыть что? Список листвью имеет итемы. Итемы, не попадающие на дисплей не активируются и нельзя с ними взаимодействовать. Мне нужно достать инфу из всего списка

Comment: если тривю динамический заполняется, то пока не раскроем - оно не существует, следовательно, мы не можем получить их.  как реализовано treeView ?

Comment: А почему бы сначала не отскроллировать список к нужному месту? Тогда уж его элементы точно будут созданы.

Comment: Не, они деактивируются, когда попадают из видимости. Я как раз проскроленный заскринил

Comment: @SeniorAutomator неизвестно как реализован. Это доступ к другой проге через винАпи с помощью UI Automation. Прога на .net

Comment: @DenisJNewb а `wpf inspector` что показывает? (это отдельная прога чтобы посмотреть AE)

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Нет прав ставить проги на рабочую машину

Comment: @DenisJNewb его просто запускать надо  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Она с SDK идет. SDK нет на машинке

Comment: @DenisJNewb ну вот нужно посмотреть как заполняется, чтобы понять как подойти к проблеме